# What does this doctrine query do?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

```
 $this->facebook_applications = Doctrine::getTable('FacebookApplication')
      ->createQuery('a')
      ->execute();
```

I don't understand how this works at all. Why is the query just 'a' and why does that seem to get a list of the applications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The static method Doctrine::getTable() gets an object that represents the FacebookApplication table.

That object has a method called createQuery(), which creates a Doctrine_Query object for querying *that table*.  The argment ('a'), specifies an alias for the table in the query.

So essentially `Doctrine::getTable('FacebookApplication')->createQuery('a')` creates a query that translates to SQL like:

```
SELECT * FROM FacebookApplication as a
```

Which, naturally, returns all rows from that table.

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't of guessed that it's making an alias. I'd accept this as an answer but SO won't let me yet because you answered so fast :P

Answer (score 2):

You can see it by using :

```
$this->facebook_applications->getSqlQuery()
```